# crosstab query provides unexpected results

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I got a bit confused by the crosstab() function inside PostgreSQL's tablefunc extension. The problem is that I want not a standard **Name-Category-Value** scheme, but something like **Name-Attribute of Name-One more attribute-Category-Value**. It doesn't seemed like a problem but soon I realised that with my DB scheme it wouldn't be as easy as I thought.

Background: I have 3 tables I want to use: *Users*, *UserEvents*, *QuestionaryAnswers*.

1. The Users table contains people
2. UserEvents contains events that happened with this people (with FK reference to Users)
3. and QuestionaryAnswers that contains answers to Questions which are referencing to UserEventId via FK.

So, tables look like this:

```
create table "Users"("Id" int, "AttrId" int, "GroupId" int);
create table "UserEvents"("Id" int, "UserId" int, "Status" varchar(20), "EventId" int);
create table "QuestionaryAnswers"("UserEventId" int, "QuestionaryItemId" int, "AnswerItemId" int);
```

Users:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."Users"("Id", "AttrId", "GroupId") 
VALUES (1, 1, 12587), (2, 1, 11092);
```

UserEvents:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."UserEvents"("Id", "UserId", "Status", "EventId") 
VALUES (142, 1, 'Checked', 2), (143, 1, 'Created', 1), (144, 2, 'Done', 2);
```

And QuestionaryAnswers:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."QuestionaryAnswers"("UserEventId", "QuestionaryItemId", "AnswerItemId") 
VALUES ('142', 1, 2),
('142', 4, 16),
('142', 5, 25),
('143', 12, 99);
('144', 12, 100);
```

Well, that's where problems are appearing. This is my crosstab query for now:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(' SELECT "UserEvents"."UserId", "QuestionaryAnswers"."UserEventId", "Users"."AttrId", "Users"."GroupId", "QuestionaryAnswers"."QuestionaryItemId", "AnswerItems"."Name"
 FROM "QuestionaryAnswers"
    LEFT JOIN "AnswerItems" ON "QuestionaryAnswers"."AnswerItemId" = "AnswerItems"."Id" 
    LEFT JOIN "UserEvent" ON "QuestionaryAnswers"."UserEventId" = "UserEvents"."Id" 
    LEFT JOIN "Users" ON "UserEvents"."UserId" = "Users"."Id"
    ORDER BY 1, 2'::text, 
'SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 21 ORDER BY 1'::text) 
crosstab("UserId" integer, "UserEventId" uuid,
"AttrId" integer, "GroupId" integer,
"Question1" text, "2" text, "3" text, "4" text,
"5" text, "6" text, "7" text, "8" text, "9" text,
"10" text, "11" text, "12" text, "13" text, "14" text,
"15" text, "16" text, "17" text, "18" text, "19" text)
```

And here all seems quite straightforward, except one little detail - categories\columns\questions are linked to different *UserEventId*'s, so basically UserEventId is picked randomly (by ORDER clause), and because of that Status attribute from the *UserEvents* table will be picked randomly too. What I want to see is separate UserEventId and Status fields that are derived by *EventId*, so there would be **UserEventId_1** and **UserEventId_2** IDs, and probably linked fields too, e.g **Status_1** and **Status_2**, like this:

```
UserId | UserEventId_EventId1 | UserEventId_EventId2 | AttrId | GroupId | Question1 | Question3 | Question4 | Question5 | Question12
-------+----------------------+----------------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
     1 |                  143 |                  142 |      1 |   12587 |           |           |        16 |        25 |         99
     2 |                      |                  144 |      1 |   11092 |           |           |           |           |        144
```

So the questions are:

1. How can I make a "category" crosstab column based on the foreign key value? I can't figure that out, probably because it's different "stacks" of categories - events and questions.
2. The whole idea of this is a bit wrong - crosstab isn't intended to show data in format that I want, so I'll describle the goal. I need a table to run simple comparative queries "how much people answered to question 1 like this and answered to question 2 like this", but I also need to filter this on "UserEvents" *Status* field and "Users" *GroupId* field, so I need either EventID or Status inside the table. Am I missing some opportunity to do this simpler or some ability to show this data in crosstab?
   P.S I am using PostgreSQL 11.1

Comment: Yes with what you write I don't see why you are doing a cross join

Comment: So I edited my question a bit to have some form of desired results. Is it OK now?

Comment: I suppose I can use LATERAL here, but I have no idea how to work with it and if someone there can explain me the way it works and some examples - I would be really happy. Otherwise, I'm fine with crosstab() except the thing I can't show FK categories + another set of categories, which looks like double crosstab

Comment: Your goal would be much clearer if you could simply throw here the sample of the table that you're trying to get

Comment: ygorbunkov, but I did so, just in form of INSERT statement because screenshot looked like crap. If you'll copy the INSERT statement in db-fiddle for example it would show the table I want.

Comment: `INSERT`statements are just fine. Only the `CREATE TABLE` statements are missing or we have nothing to insert into. And your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: Done, I added corresponding information

Comment: Please show table "AnswerItems" as well

Comment: I set up a dbfiddle (achieving your result without crosstab) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ba0b5f6ee86aef407eafec8b68c8783b But I don't really understand what's your problem. Nevertheless: Where does the value "144" in the last column come from?

Comment: Next time, please start with the *goal*, not with the presumed solution.

Comment: S-Man, cool solution! It doesn't work in real case though (I thought simplified example would be enough, but in real database event IDs are in UUID format and neither aggregation function works for it. Is there any alternative for FILTER clause?

Answer (score 0):

So far, what you have described may be achieved without crosstab invocation:

```
select u1."Id" as "UserId", u1."GroupId", e1."Status", 
    q1."QuestionaryItemId", q1."AnswerItemId", count(*)
from "Users" u1
left join "UserEvents" e1
on u1."Id" = e1."UserId"
left join "QuestionaryAnswers" q1
on q1."UserEventId"=e1."Id"
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

You may check out the result [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n9QJttVbnKmw4vqZW6qcuk/0).

Comment: But that's definitely not what I want - in my example above I showed that I want to represent every question as a separate column so I'll have an easy way to run queries with conditions like "WHERE question1 = 'something' AND question2 = 'something_other' ". That's important because that table is shown in GUI SQL tool

Comment: I have answered before I saw your updated question. And my solution obviously does what was requested initially (split by user, question, quantity of corresponding answers). However, there's no problem in running queries with `...where "QuestionaryItemId"=...` against dataset returned by my query. Moreover, I'm affraid this 'double pivoting' by EventId and QuestionId may require two corresponding crosstabs and later joining them up together, since sql query fed to `crosstab()` expects three columns with row key, criteria, value, respectively.

Comment: I see... Okay, I will try to make crosstab join crosstab and then report results, but it doesn't seem like a great\clean solution, if there's more convenient ways I'd be glad to discover them